# get size of maximized matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to open a matplotlib figure maximized and I'd like to get the size of the figure in inches. This yields the same value no matter if the figure is maximized or not:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
# figManager.window.showMaximized()

fig = plt.gcf()
height = fig.get_size_inches()[1]
print(height)
```

```
4.8
```

Any hints?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same results. When I maximize the figure, your code yields different value for me.

Comment: @ywbaek Interesting! By maximizing, you mean commenting in the `figManager` lines, right? Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the time is takes to maximise/draw the figure itself. You could be catching the size of the figure before it is resized.

Introducing any length of pause solves the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()

plt.pause(0.0001)

fig = plt.gcf()
height = fig.get_size_inches()[1]
print(height)
# 9.56      Commenting out the pause gives me the result 4.8
```